# Library for DocsClient

Tags: android, google-docs-api

I'm writing a program which must download documents from google docs. I have downloaded [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/docs-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/docs/cmdline/DocsSample.java?repo=samples&r=3702d857761f7caae83306a9016f73d5c1fc01f1) example , but its haven't attached jar files. So I havent found any jar, which contains `com.google.api.services.docs.DocsClient` class. Could anybody tell me the jar , which contains this class.
Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. The solution is that you need to install maven plugin for  Eclipse IDE , and it will download all dependency libraries.
[Here](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/02/24/install-maven-plugin-for-eclipse/) you can find the instructions for installing Maven plugin , and [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Eclipse) is instructions for downloading libraries.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your DocsClient class is [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/docs-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/docs/cmdline/DocsClient.java?repo=samples&r=43b27a71a63db8a8c481a6f3e95ffa9533e01865). Check if it's the correct one.